# Converting Tags to Array of Tags

Tags: typescript, pulumi

I have some code I found for assigning tag values to resources in AWS via typescript. The problem is, one of the resources (autoScaling Groups) handles tags differently than all other resources. Instead of defining all my tag values twice, I'm trying to figure out a programatic way to do it.

Here is my current tag variable:

```
const tags = [{
  Name: "ServerName"
  tContact: "john@doe.com"
  tEnv: "DEV"
  tOwner: "John doe",
  tProject: "Typescript",
}];
```

If I were to create a 2nd manually for the different tag type, it would be:

```
const tags2 = 
   [
    {
      key: "Name",
      propagateAtLaunch: true,
      value: "ServerName",
    },
    {
      key: "tContact",
      propagateAtLaunch: true,
      value: "john@doe.com",
    },
    {
      key: "tEnv",
      propagateAtLaunch: true,
      value: "DEV",
    },
    {
      key: "tOwner",
      propagateAtLaunch: true,
      value: "John Doe",
    },
    {
      key: "tProject",
      propagateAtLaunch: true,
      value: "Typescript",
    }
  ];
```

I'm new to typescript, but I'm sure there's even nearly a one liner to do this. I was thinking of a for loop and strings, but I'm sure there is some sort of `apply` and redirect I'm missing.

Comment: `tags` appears to be an array containing one (or more) objects. Is it always going to contain just one that one object, or will there possibly be more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `.map` the object entries `Object.entries` like this

```
Object.entries(tags[0]).map(([key, value]) => (
      {
        key: key, 
        value: tags[0][key], 
        propagateAtLaunch: true
      }));
```

```js
const tags = [{
  Name: "ServerName",
  tContact: "john@doe.com",
  tEnv: "DEV",
  tOwner: "John doe",
  tProject: "Typescript",
},
{
  Name: "ServerName1",
  tContact: "john@doe.com",
  tEnv: "DEV1",
  tOwner: "John doe",
  tProject: "Typescript",
}];
//let obj = tags[0];
//console.log(obj)
let results = [];
let result = tags.forEach(c=> results.push(Object.entries(c).map(([key, value]) => ({key: key, value: tags[0][key], propagateAtLaunch: true}))));
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Since I have 5 tags, does that mean I'd have to declare 5 object as well for each tag?

Comment: Thanks! Now I have to figure out the typing :) `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ tContact: string;....`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that **ES2017** didn't like the typing. So I had to change tags to be of type `any`.

```
const tags: any = [{
  Name: "ServerName",
  tContact: "john@doe.com",
  tEnv: "DEV",
  tOwner: "John doe",
  tProject: "Typescript",
}
```

Then I used the code from your first submission:

```
let result = Object.entries(tags[0]).map(([key, value]) => 
  ({ key: key, value: tags[0][key], propagateAtLaunch: true }));
```